# I have "const player" and "const enemy", both using "new Sprite()". However, if I move using "document.onkeydown", only one of them moves. Why?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a tutorial from the YouTube channel Chris Courses (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyqbNFMDRGQ&list=UU9Yp2yz6-pwhQuPlIDV_mjA&index=4), but at the same time trying to implement a few things I already know. In this case I'm trying to achieve the same that he does, but using a few different approaches.

I have a problem though. I created a class "Sprite" and a "const enemy" as well as "const player", both using the Sprite class. The Sprite class uses another class, which is the "Controls" class.

If I only declare "const player" (or "const enemy"), but **not** the second one, I can move the character just fine.
If both are declared, however, only one of them moves.

I don't understand why, though. In my understanding `const player = new Sprite();` and `const enemy = new Sprite();` means, that I create a **new** set of data for player **and** enemy. I expect that both move at the same time if I press a key. But only the last declared one moves, not the prior one.

I appreciate your time trying to explain this to me. Also, advice is always welcomed!

```js
"use strict"

// sprite.js
class Sprite {
    constructor({ character, position, velocity, width, height, gravity = 0.2 }) {
        this.character = character;
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.gravity = gravity;
        
        this.controls = new Controls();
    }

    draw() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fillRect(
            this.position.x,
            this.position.y,
            this.width,
            this.height
        );
        context.closePath();
    }

    update() {
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
        this.position.x += this.velocity.x;

        this.#applyGravity();
        this.#move();
    }

    #applyGravity() {
        if(this.position.y + this.height + this.velocity.y >= canvas.height) {
            this.velocity.y = 0;
        }
        else {
            this.velocity.y += this.gravity;
        }
    }

    #move() {
        if(this.controls) {
            if(this.controls.up && this.controls.lastKey === "up") {
                this.velocity.y = -1;
            }
            else if(this.controls.down && this.controls.lastKey === "down") {
                this.velocity.y = 1;
            }
            else if(this.controls.left && this.controls.lastKey === "left") {
                this.velocity.x = -1;
            }
            else if(this.controls.right && this.controls.lastKey === "right") {
                this.velocity.x = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}




// controls.js
class Controls {
    constructor() {
        this.up = false;
        this.down = false;
        this.left = false;
        this.right = false;
        this.lastKey = "";

        this.#addEventListeners();
    }

    #addEventListeners() {
        document.onkeydown = (event => {
            switch(event.key) {
                case "ArrowUp":
                    this.up = true;
                    this.lastKey = "up";
                    break;

                case "ArrowDown":
                    this.down = true;
                    this.lastKey = "down";
                    break;

                case "ArrowLeft":
                    this.left = true;
                    this.lastKey = "left";
                    break;

                case "ArrowRight":
                    this.right = true;
                    this.lastKey = "right";
                    break;
            }
        });

        document.onkeyup = (event => {
            switch(event.key) {
                case "ArrowUp":
                    this.up = false;
                    break;

                case "ArrowDown":
                    this.down = false;
                    break;

                case "ArrowLeft":
                    this.left = false;
                    break;

                case "ArrowRight":
                    this.right = false;
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}

// script.js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const player = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: 100,
        y: 100
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    width: 50,
    height: 150
});

const enemy = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: 800,
        y: 100
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    width: 50,
    height: 150
});

let animationID;

function animate() {
    animationID = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    canvas.width = 1024;
    canvas.height = 576;

    player.draw();
    player.update();
    enemy.draw();
    enemy.update();
}

animate();
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: darkgrey;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
#canvas {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fighting Game inspired by Chris Courses</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

<!-- commented out since I merged controls.js and sprite.js into one file for this code snippet -->
<!-- <script src="controls.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="sprite.js"></script> -->
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Here's a useful debugging technique that is also helpful for [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): removing parts of your code bit by bit until you have the simplest version that still demonstrates the problem you're having. It makes it so answerers don't have to understand your whole program and can focus on the actual code question, and also helps you narrow in on what the problem might be as well!

Comment: Looks like each instance of Controls **overwrites** the event listeners of every previous instance.

Comment: You are replacing the `document.onkeydown` event, so there can only be one.  Try using `document.addEventListener("keydown", fn)` if you want two listeners active.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the problem is coming from `document.onkeydown`, which can be only defined once per DOM element. So when you are creating two instances of your `Sprite` object, the second constructor overrides the onkeydown event from the first sprite.

But you can add multiple event listeners with [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?retiredLocale=de), just keep in mind that tose events don't have `on` in their names. So it's just `keydown` and `keyup`. A full list of events are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events?retiredLocale=de)

I modified your code to show it's usage.

```js
"use strict"

// sprite.js
class Sprite {
    constructor({ character, position, velocity, width, height, gravity = 0.2 }) {
        this.character = character;
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.gravity = gravity;
        
        this.controls = new Controls();
    }

    draw() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fillRect(
            this.position.x,
            this.position.y,
            this.width,
            this.height
        );
        context.closePath();
    }

    update() {
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
        this.position.x += this.velocity.x;

        this.#applyGravity();
        this.#move();
    }

    #applyGravity() {
        if(this.position.y + this.height + this.velocity.y >= canvas.height) {
            this.velocity.y = 0;
        }
        else {
            this.velocity.y += this.gravity;
        }
    }

    #move() {
        if(this.controls) {
            if(this.controls.up && this.controls.lastKey === "up") {
                this.velocity.y = -1;
            }
            else if(this.controls.down && this.controls.lastKey === "down") {
                this.velocity.y = 1;
            }
            else if(this.controls.left && this.controls.lastKey === "left") {
                this.velocity.x = -1;
            }
            else if(this.controls.right && this.controls.lastKey === "right") {
                this.velocity.x = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}




// controls.js
class Controls {
    constructor() {
        this.up = false;
        this.down = false;
        this.left = false;
        this.right = false;
        this.lastKey = "";

        this.#addEventListeners();
    }

    #addEventListeners() {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            switch(event.key) {
                case "ArrowUp":
                    this.up = true;
                    this.lastKey = "up";
                    break;

                case "ArrowDown":
                    this.down = true;
                    this.lastKey = "down";
                    break;

                case "ArrowLeft":
                    this.left = true;
                    this.lastKey = "left";
                    break;

                case "ArrowRight":
                    this.right = true;
                    this.lastKey = "right";
                    break;
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
            switch(event.key) {
                case "ArrowUp":
                    this.up = false;
                    break;

                case "ArrowDown":
                    this.down = false;
                    break;

                case "ArrowLeft":
                    this.left = false;
                    break;

                case "ArrowRight":
                    this.right = false;
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}

// script.js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const enemy = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: 800,
        y: 100
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    width: 50,
    height: 200
});

const player = new Sprite({
    position: {
        x: 100,
        y: 100
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    width: 50,
    height: 150
});

let animationID;

function animate() {
    animationID = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    canvas.width = 1024;
    canvas.height = 576;

    enemy.draw();
    enemy.update();
        player.draw();
    player.update();
}

animate();
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: darkgrey;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
#canvas {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Fighting Game inspired by Chris Courses</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>

<!-- commented out since I merged controls.js and sprite.js into one file for this code snippet -->
<!-- <script src="controls.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="sprite.js"></script> -->
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: "So when you are creating two instances of your Sprite object, the second constructor overrides the onkeydown event from the first sprite." Okay, so I basically have two Sprites (let's call them S1 and S2 for now). S1 (should be for player?) and S2 (should be for enemy?) use the same onkeydown event but in seperate instances. If S2 overrides S1, why does only enemy (should be using S2) move? I mean, both still are the same keydown "infos", representing the movement. In other words: Wouldn't I expect player AND enemy to use S2, since S1 has been overridden?

Comment: You've created two objects from type "Sprite" which both create a new instance of "Controls" in their constructor. So you have 2x Sprite and 2x Controls, and since in Controls you define the onkeydown/onkeyup the second object from Controls is overriding the events from the first Controls. So basically the first Controls is left without any events. What you could also do is keep your version of controls and create one global object from it. Then use the same object in both enemy and player.